# Where MPI locates new processes?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm running several processes with mpirun in a node with 36 cpus and 72 threads (hyperthreading). When I run them with different mpirun calls (each with -np 2) they run in the same cpus, decreasing the efficiency of the processes. With ps command I see that when I send 7

```
mpirun -np 2 ./foo
```

calls, all the processes are running in just 4 threads. Anyone knows how to solve it? I want to distribute the processes across all threads for maximize the efficiency.

Comment: Which MPI library are you using?

Comment: Open MPI 1.10.7

Comment: That's a pretty antique version you should upgrade ...

Comment: I know it, but I'm not the cluster admin :(

Comment: you can install Open MPI in your $HOME directory, no need for admin privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default with Open MPI is to bind MPI tasks to cores with invoked with `-np 2`. There is no connection between jobs, so all MPI jobs get pinned to the same two cores (`0` and `1` iirc).

A suboptimal solution is to avoid binding, and let the Linux scheduler takes care of that

```
mpirun --bind-to none -np 2 ./foo
```

A better solution is to use a resource manager such as SLURM, configure cpuset or similar so all your jobs get allocated on disjoint set of two cores.